# trouble with some basic javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with some basic javascript:

```
function tank(){
    this.width = 50;
    this.length = 70;
}

function Person(job) {
    this.job = job;
    this.married = true;
}
var tank1 = tank();
console.log(tank1.length);  //returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

var gabby = new Person("student");
console.log(gabby.married);  //returns: true
```

The first console.log does not work, but the second console.log works. I'm a javascript beginner and I'm at a loss as to why the length property is undefined. Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed `new` keyword:

```
var tank1 = new tank();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute tank(), the execution context for the function is the `window` object. What you are doing is adding "width" and "length" fields to the window object, and you can see this if you execute `window.length` and `window.width` after the `tank()` call. You should see the values 70 and 50. Since the `tank` function does not return a value, the statement `var tank1 = tank();` effectively sets `tank1` to `undefined`, hence the error you are getting.

In the second statement, you are calling the `Person` constructor, so by the time `function Person(job) {...}` executes, `this` is a reference to the `Person` object that you are creating. The `new` statement does the following:

1. Create the `Person` object.
2. Calls the constructor "`function Person(...)`", setting the `this` to a reference to the object it just created.
3. Returns the new `Person` object to the caller after the function returns.

For more information on the execution context, see [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2265-Changing-The-Execution-Context-Of-JavaScript-Functions-Using-Call-And-Apply-.htm).